# How to set state for each element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array with arrays in there, and I want to display only the first 4 elements from each nested array on the first render. Then I have a `showMore` button which should show new 4 items from the array when clicked, but my solution affects all other elements instead of only the clicked one. Is there a way to set the slice parameters dynamically for each of those arrays? Here is the code sample of what I have tried

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(4);
  const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ];

  const mappedArr = arr.map((e) => {
    return e.slice(start, end);
  });

  const showMore = () => {
    setStart(start + end);
    setEnd(end + 4);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {mappedArr.map((e) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <span>{e}</span>
            <span onClick={showMore}>{">"}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the live codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-http-vl7gb?file=/src/App.js)
How can I achieve this? Any example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need separate `start` and `end` for each subarray, rather than having only a single one of each for the whole component.

To make the data easier to manage, consider transforming each subarray into an object containing `start` and `end` as well as the subarray.

```js
const initialArr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];
function App() {
    const [arr, setArr] = React.useState(() => initialArr.map(
        subarr => ({ start: 0, end: 4, subarr })
    ));
    const showMore = (i) => () => {
        setArr(arr.map((e, j) => j !== i ? e : ({
            ...e,
            start: e.start + 4,
            end: e.end + 4,
        })));
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {arr.map((e, i) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <span>{e.subarr.slice(e.start, e.end)}</span>
                        <span onClick={showMore(i)}>{">"}</span>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```